# Достать значения с помощью регулярок

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++11

Необходимо разбить следующую строку(заодно лучше с регулярками разберусь)

```
Location: http://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=wHKcWInnDurA7gThta_YBw
```

на:

- протокол `http`
- адрес `google.ru`
- параметры `?gfe_rd=cr&ei=wHKcWInnDurA7gThta_YBw`...

Cделал с помощью алгоритмов STL(два раза **std::find_if** и три раза **std::copy**), но как-то это убого смотрится.

Как это сделать с помощью регулярок, и будет ли это быстрее?

Comment: `^Location: ([a-z]+):\/\/(.*)\/(.*)$`. Пример: https://regex101.com/r/YhJQho/1

Comment: хм, благодарствую

Comment: а по скорости быстрее будет чем алгоритмы со строками?

Comment: @Arhad, хм, надо google.ru а не www.google.ru... чет не могу никак допереть

Comment: `а по скорости быстрее будет...` — не знаю, зависит от реализации стандартной библиотеки. `надо google.ru` — https://regex101.com/r/YhJQho/3 (работает и при опущенном `www`); смысл каждого символа описан (на английском) в правом верхнем углу страницы по ссылке.

Comment: благодарствую...

Comment: Или ещё так: [`^Location: ([a-z]+)://(?:www\.)?([^/]+)/?([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/frtUB5/1).

Comment: хм, у вас даже покруче будет

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ваше выражение даже быстрее (за меньшее число шагов) отрабатывает, чем моё.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27745/4279)

Comment: Чтобы колесо не изобретать, можно существующие библиотеки использовать такие как [Folly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30386166/4279).

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Регулярные выражения не всегда оптимизируют скорость выполнения программ, зачастую обычные строковые методы работают быстрее шаблонов.

В данном конкертном случае регулярное выражение можно задать следующим образом:

```
^Location:\s+([a-z]+)://(?:www\.)?([^/]+)/?([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))?$
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/frtUB5/3)

- `^` - якорь начало строки
- `Location:` - последовательность символов
- `\s+` - 1+ пробелов
- `([a-z]+)` - (*захватывающая группа 1*) 1+ лат. букв
- `://`  - последовательность символов
- `(?:www\.)?` - необязательная подстрока `www.`
- `([^/]+)` - (*захватывающая группа 2*) 1+ символов, отличных от `/`
- `/?` - необязательный слеш
- `([^?]*)` - (*захватывающая группа 3*) 0+ символов, отличных от `?`
- `(?:\?(.*))?` - необязательная последовательность...

  - `\?` - знак вопроса
  - `(.*)` - (*захватывающая группа 4*) 0+ любых (кроме перевода строки) символов
- `$` -

Пример использования регулярного выражения в С++ (т.к. `regex_match` требует полного совпадения строки, якоря не нужны):

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s("Location: http://www.gogggle.ru/ru/index.php?gfe_rd=cr&ei=wHKcWInnDurA7gThta_YBw");
    regex r(R"(Location:\s+([a-z]+)://(?:www\.)?([^/]+)/?([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))?)");
    smatch matches;
    if (regex_match(s, matches, r)) {
        cout << "Протокол: " << matches.str(1) << endl;
        cout << "Домен: " << matches.str(2) << endl;
        cout << "Путь: " << matches.str(3) << endl;
        cout << "Строка запроса: " << matches.str(4) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

См. [C++-демо](https://ideone.com/MEI6aG)